# Is there a way to make Photostream take up less space on an iPad without turning it off entirely?

Tags: ipad, photo-stream

A member of my family has a 16GB iPad which keeps reporting that it is out of space. One big occupier of space on the iPad seems to be Photostream pictures. Is there a way to a) figure out how much space Photostream is occupying on the device and b) limit or reduce that space without disabling Photostream entirely? I'd prefer something easy like a preference box I've just overlooked, but some sort of script-based hack that inserts a bunch of minimal-sized photos into the stream to take up space in the 1000 most recent but not take up much storage space could be an option.

FWIW, our main use for Photostream is to get the pictures taken on the iPad into iPhoto on the Mac automatically, and secondarily to get access on the iPad to photos taken by camera then copied into iPhoto on the Mac. I'd love to be able to still do these things but not have to give up the space to store 1000 photos on the iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) figure out how much space Photostream is occupying on the device

- Go to settings
- General -> Usage
- wait until the top is done and then click on Photos and Camera
- The next page under Photo and Camera has the space used for Camera Roll, Photo Library, and the Photo Stream.

b) reduce space.

After taking photos you can edit and crop, delete the ones that you do not want.  It saves the last 1000 photos for 30 days so if you take a lot of photos, copy them when you can.  Photo stream is there for you to easily sync your photos from one device to all.  After you have the photo, copy it to your mac and remove them from your photo stream.  After 30 days or over 1000 photos you might start to lose photos.

Comment: If you delete photos from Photostream, does that mean that Photostream will hold less than the latest 1000 photos, or that they are replaced by other photos?

Comment: I believe it will pull the last 1000, within 30 days.  If you delete one and still have more photos within 30 days it would put them in place.  Mass import then delete works well.  Again, the idea of photostream isn't backup but having like the most recent photos on all devices.

Comment: But if it does that, it defeats the purpose of deleting to save space. While I'd love for this solution to work, it sounds like it won't accomplish what I'm hoping for, which is freeing up space on the iPad.

Comment: Apple doesn't have a way to limit photostream per individual users.  Everyone has the same settings.  Do you have more than 1,000 photos per 30 days?  If your sole goal is to save space there are good ways to do that.  I would recommend deleting photos from your Camera Roll.  Looking at how much data each app is saving is a good way.  See what is needed and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Adobe revel. It doesn't take up room on devices and it keeps all photos in sync on all apple devices apart from Apple TV